# CImg library not compiling in Dev c++

Tags: c++, cimg

I have set up dev c++ on my computer and am trying to compile the simple C++ hello world code with it but it does not compile and gives these error codes

```
C:\Users\Ignatius\Documents\testing.o   testing.cpp:(.text$_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay5paintEv[__ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay5paintEv]+0xb2): undefined reference to `_imp__SetDIBitsToDevice@48'

C:\Users\Ignatius\Documents\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

25      C:\Users\Ignatius\Documents\Makefile.win    recipe for target 'test.exe' failed
```

The code I used was

**main.cpp**

```
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
    CImg<unsigned char> img(640, 400, 1, 3);
    img.fill(0);
    unsigned char purple[] = {225, 0, 225};
    img.draw_text(100, 100, "Hello world", purple);
    img.display("My first CImg code");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Currently this is my only file. I downloaded CImg online and dropped folders in the correct directory and the .h file in the correct directory it gives no syntax errors but wont compile can someone help me?

In the Makefile.win the lines highlighted in the assembly code was (if that helps)

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: You need to link against the right library - by the looks of it, the cimg library.  Read the CImg docs

Comment: What do you mean? I did what I was instructed

Answer (score 0):

`CImg` is a *"header only"* libray so you don't need to link against it. All you need to do is determine where `CImg.h` is located and tell the compiler with `-I thatplace`.

So if `CImg.h` is in `/opt/fred`, you would do

```
c++ program.c -I /opt/fred -o program
```

If you need to link to a library, such as `gdi32`, you will probably need to add `-lgdi32` to the end:

```
c++ program.c -I /opt/fred -lgdi32 -o program
```

Comment: Wait what? Well what if I want to test it in dev C++?

Comment: I put the .h file in C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include

Comment: That's a dev C++ issue. All I am saying is that with `CImg`, there are no libraries that you must link against and that all you need do is tell the compiler where the header files are - i.e. the *Include* files - using the `-I` switch or however you do that in `dev C++`.

Comment: Okay... so how do I include them in my project tho?

Comment: All I am doing is trying to make a small GUI program

Comment: Its relieving I dont need those other files but how do I include them into my dev c++ IDE?

Comment: I guess `dev C++` is a graphical dev environment and it will have a *build setting* or somesuch called *"header file search path"* or *"include path"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell:  Look at the error.  It's coming from `ld` - the linker - not the compiler.  Thus we know it's not a failure to find the header file.  It's failing to find a compiled function.  If it's not a CImg function, it must be a Windows API function - so the OP needs to throw the dev C++ switch to link against the windows API functions.

Comment: Oh so how do I do that? I really need this library

Comment: Google SetDIBitsToDevice. You will find an MSDN page. This tells you to link with gdi32.lib. So add gdi32.lib (or possibly -lgdi32 in an msys/mingw/cygwin environment) to LIBS.

Comment: I see it so what is this supposed to do? Do I put it in a file?

Comment: @user6031759 It looks like CImg uses GDI to do its displaying, so you need to link with the GDI library. That means you need to make sure `LIBS` (which you show in your question) contains the path to wherever the `gdi32.lib` file is. So, use whatever tools Windows provides to find `gdi32.lib` and then put the path to the containing directory in your `LIBS` variable.

Comment: Oh okay, is gdi32.lib already on my windows system? How can I link to it?

Comment: I have added that in now - please try again.